# How to redirect to a new page in Angular 4 through button click?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

In `home.component.html` page I want the button to redirect the url to a new page when clicked.

I expect that when I clicked the button, the current url `http://localhost:24282/home`, will be redirected to this url `http://localhost:24282/master` and `master.component.html` page will be shown.

The issue is that, though the url is redirected to `http://localhost:24282/master` when I clicked the button, but still I'm on the current page `home.component.html`.  I wasn't completely redirected to the master page `master.component.html`

Below are the implementation.

**app.routing.ts**

```
    import { ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './Components/home.component';
import { MasterComponent } from './Components/master/master.component';
import { PageNotFoundComponent } from "./Components/common/page-not-found.component";

const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
    { path: 'master', component: MasterComponent },
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
];

export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

**app.module.ts**

```
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { routing } from './app.routing';
import { HomeComponent } from './Components/home.component';
import { MasterComponent } from './Components/master/master.component';
import { PageNotFoundComponent } from "./Components/common/page-not-found.component";

@NgModule({
    imports: [BrowserModule, routing],
    declarations: [AppComponent, HomeComponent, MasterComponent, PageNotFoundComponent],
    providers: [{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/' }],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**app.component.ts** - where the newChange() method is defined

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
    selector: 'moc-landing',
    templateUrl: './app/Components/home.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app/Components/home.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
constructor(private router: Router) {}

    newChange(): void {
        this.router.navigateByUrl('master');
    }
}
```

**home.component.html**

`<button id="new" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="newChange()">New Change Request</button>`

I'm not sure if I have correctly used `router.navigateByUrl` or is there any alternative way?

In ASP.NET MVC, this is fairly easy to do using razor's URL helper classes (e.g. `@Url.Action`).

But in Angular 4 (which I'm pretty new to it), I don't know how to implement it. I have gone through some research, but couldn't find any related to this.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: try ` this.router.navigateByUrl('/master');`

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer sorry, I tried it, but it didn't work.

Comment: @Juniuz try this this.router.navigate(["/master"]);

Comment: how about use `navigate`?
  this.router.navigate(['./master']);

Comment: @Gautam it didn't work either with `this.router.navigate(["/master"])`

Comment: @RachChen, I tried it also, but didn't work too.

Comment: @Juniuz do you have any other errors in your console? sometimes it restricts the navigation

Comment: @VeenaK.Suresh could be, but I don't see any thrown errors in browser's console when I click the button.

Comment: @Juniuz Perhaps your issue was with your _app.routing.ts_. Nowadays the module's class is exported, e.g. `@NgModule({imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],exports: [RouterModule]})` followed by `export class AppRoutingModule {}`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you are using a link (`<a>`), you only need the [*routerLink* directive/parameter](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLink):

```html
<a class="btn" routerLink="/votes">Check votes</a>
```

If you are using a button (`<button>`), you need a `(click)` event:

```html
<button class="btn" (click)="goToVotes()">Check votes</button>
```

It is preferable to create a function/method in this case, since it is a **good practice to keep private parameters** in your component's constructor, i.e. don't use [*router.navigate()*](https://angular.io/api/router/Router#navigate) directly on your HTML (avoids 'router' warnings due to using a private member of the component).

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
// component details here...
export class MyComponent  {
  constructor(private router: Router){ }

  goToVotes($myParam: string = ''): void {
    const navigationDetails: string[] = ['/votes'];
    if($myParam.length) {
      navigationDetails.push($myParam);
    }
    this.router.navigate(navigationDetails);
  }
}
```

The *goToVotes* method above will also add a second value to the *navigate*'s array if its argument is not empty, and thus:

```html
<button class="btn" (click)="goToVotes('ca')">Go vote</button>
```

Would redirect to `/votes/ca`.

Answer (score 21):

Try this

```
<button (click)="router.navigate(['/master']);">
   <span>Go to master Page</span>
</button>
```

OR

in your home.html

```
<button (click)="goToPage('master')">
   <span>Go to master Page</span>
</button>
```

and in your home component

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

constructor(private router: Router){
}

function goToPage(pageName:string){
  this.router.navigate([`${pageName}`]);
}
```

Comment: thanks for this.  I tried your code, unfortunately, it didn't work.

Answer (score 8):

I agree with Veena K. Suresh on his solution on navigating using a click event but you can also pass along data through the same trick

1. Import the  `router` module into your current component:

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
```

2. Inject it to your constructor

```
constructor(
    private router: Router
  ) { }
```

3. Add `router.navigate` to the anchor tag

```html
<a (click)="router.navigate(['/search',search.value]);" class="search-area__icon"> 
    <i class="la la-search"></i>
</a>
```

Answer (score 5):

`navigateByUrl`  always expects an absolute URL.

```
i.e. router.navigateByUrl("/team/33/user/11");
```

If you want to provide a relative route, you can use `navigate` instead:

```
router.navigate(['team', 33, 'user', 11], {relativeTo: route});
```

Comment: so, I did this `this.router.navigate(['master'], {relativeTo: route});` but, I got a swiggly red line in `route` saying Cannot find name 'route'. how do I declare it?

Answer (score 0):

Late reply, but still posting the answer with the hope that my answer could be useful to someone else.

Modify the code inside `app.component.html` file like below.

```
<div>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```